# What are the Rust borrowing rules regarding mutable internal references?

Tags: rust

It's not intuitive to me why a program like

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    buf: [u8; 16],
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test {
            buf: [0u8; 16],
        }       
    }   

    fn hi(&mut self) {
        self.buf[0] = 'H' as u8; 
        self.buf[1] = 'i' as u8; 
        self.buf[2] = '!' as u8; 
        self.print();
    }   

    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }   
}

fn main() {
    Test::new().hi();
}
```

compiles and runs without any problem, but a program like

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum State {
    Testing([u8; 16]),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    state: State,
}       

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test {
            state: State::Testing([0u8; 16]),
        }
    }   

    fn hi(&mut self) {
        match self.state {
            State::Testing(ref mut buf) => {
                buf[0] = 'H' as u8;
                buf[1] = 'i' as u8;
                buf[2] = '!' as u8;
                self.print();
            },
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    Test::new().hi();
}
```

errors during compilation with an error of

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because
>   `self.state.0` is also borrowed as mutable

Since both programs do essentially the same thing, the second doesn't seem like it would be somehow more unsafe from a memory perspective. I know there must be something about the borrowing and scoping rules that I must be missing, but have no idea what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `match` statement, you borrow `self.state`. Borrow scopes are lexical, so it is borrowed in the entire `match` block. When you call `self.print()`, you need to borrow `self`. But that is not possible, because part of `self` is already borrowed. If you move `self.print()` after the `match` statement, it will work.

Regarding the lexical borrow scope, you can read more in the second part of [Two bugs in the borrow checker every Rust developer should know about](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/12/two-bugs-in-the-borrow-checker-every-rust-developer-should-know-about/). Related issues: [#6393](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393), [#811](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811).

Answer (score 3):

In order to make your `hi` function work you just need to move `print` out of the scope of the mutable borrow introduced in its `match` expression:

```
fn hi(&mut self) {
    match self.state {
        State::Testing(ref mut buf) => {
            buf[0] = 'H' as u8;
            buf[1] = 'i' as u8;
            buf[2] = '!' as u8;
        },
    }
    self.print();
}
```

Your two variants are not equivalent due to the presence of the `match` block in the second case. I don't know how to directly access the tuple struct in the `enum` without pattern matching (or if this is even possible right now), but if it was the case, then there would in fact be not much difference and both versions would work.

Comment: You could use `if let` to pattern match rather than `match` here, though I find `match` more "future proof".

Comment: Why is match more future proof? Isn't "if let" stable?

Comment: @avl_sweden I meant the possibility of the `State` enum having more variants as the project expands.